# Ionic unit test without chrome

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

How to disable the whole browser inclusion in karma unit tests for ionic?
I followed the [default tutorial](https://leifwells.github.io/2017/08/27/testing-in-ionic-configure-existing-projects-for-testing/) and in keeps opening a browser. Do not need that. Terminal report is enough.

- The watch functionality seems to not be working. It restarts when I save a file but does not reload the content.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question right. You will always need a browser as a runtime to execute your tests... If you want Chrome to start headless, you can create a custom launcher in your karma.conf.js like so: `customLaunchers: {
      ChromiumHeadlessNoSandbox: {
        base: 'Chromium',
        flags: [
          '--headless',
          '--no-sandbox',
          '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
          '--disable-gpu',
        ],
      }
    }`

Comment: Above is pretty much a paste of my custom _Chromium_ launcher, you will have to adjust it to your needs, but I guess you get the idea. An example with for headless Chrome can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/headless-karma-mocha-chai#creating_your_own_headless_chrome_launcher)

Comment: Is there a way to run it in the terminal only, without any browser. Such as `py.test` for instance? Just an executable, one time run. No recompile.

Comment: I think using a headless browser is the closest you will get, as I pointed out you **need** a browser as a runtime for your tests. Good thing is: You won't see any of this, everything happens in background and you only get your terminal report.

Comment: For a one time run without recompiling call karma with the `--single-run` flag like: `karma start ./test-config/karma.conf.js --single-run`

Comment: Ok, I'll try running headless

Comment: @Phonolog Could it be that the Ionic build platform and karma test platform conflict? Seems all my `www/build/*js` files are gone and I can not run my app. `main.js` & others are missing...

Comment: I had no problems like this... Maybe check if your paths are correct, otherwise this might be worth another question

Comment: I ended up installing Jest for unit testing. Much more lightweight than the whole Karma setup. Thanks for your help though, appreciate it!